# Azure Maps Libraries are not Importing (Services and Animation APIs)

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-maps

I am trying to make an Angular app which will show the optimised route along with direction of a set of destinations. I installed Azure Maps SDK in my app and started using the APIs. All things are working fine but not the animation API.
I am importing maps like this

```
import * as atlas from 'azure-maps-control';
```

and then using the animation api as per the documentation:

```
this.animation = atlas.animation.moveAlongRoute(this.routePoints, this.pin, { 
              

  //Specify the property that contains the timestamp.
              timestampProperty: 'timestamp',

  //Capture metadata so that data driven styling can be done.

  captureMetadata: true,
  
  loop: document.getElementById('loopAnimation'),
  reverse: document.getElementById('reverseAnimation'),
  rotationOffset: (document.getElementById('reverseAnimation'))? 90: 0,
  
  //Animate such that 1 second of animation time = 1 minute of data time.
  speedMultiplier: 60,

  //If following enabled, add a map to the animation.
  map: (document.getElementById('followSymbol'))? this.map: null,

  //Camera options to use when following.
  zoom: 15,
  pitch: 45,
  rotate: true

          });
      });
  });
}
```

But it is giving the error like

> Property 'animation' does not exist on type 'typeof atlas'

I also needed the service module, so I import it from

```
import * as  atlases from 'azure-maps-rest';
```

This time by using this import, I was able to use atlases.services module, but now some interface error is coming stating that

> Type 'undefined' does not satisfy the constraint 'IBaseGeojson'.
>
> 2153  G extends IBaseGeojson = undefined> = D & (G extends undefined ?
> {

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `azure-maps-animations` JavaScript file from the `dist` folder into your project from this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-animations) to use with azure maps web sdk.

And for Azure Maps Service Module, `atlas-services-ui` JavaScript and CSS files and the `localization` folder from the `dist` folder into your project from this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-services-ui).

Comment: Thanks for helping ! I added the JavaScript dist file as well but it is not working i was not able to use the function present in it. Can you Please elaborate some more on how to do it . Should i add all the files or just the dist file can do the job. As i am using should i also download the index.d.ts file as well?